# Change Gnome terminal (Bash) profile when changing to different user in the same terminal (e.g. root)

Tags: 11.04, gnome, command-line

Is it possible to change the profile of a terminal upon switching user in the same terminal?

Actually my goal is to change the terminal to a profile which indicates to me that it is a terminal as 'root' and that I better be very careful. Of course I am always very careful with root, and to improve that even more, I want to change the profile of the terminal so that it clearly shows to me that I'm currently using a terminal that has root-priviliges.

So for clarity: I don't want to make a shortcut to open a bash terminal with a certain profile, I am thinking of some edits to .bashrc which detects a user change and can switch to a profile.

Is this possible, and if yes, how? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to edit `.bashrc` file for `root` user and add there whatever you need to have that different profile.

For example, it's usual to set `PS1` in `.bashrc` to provide a different prompt (one that ends with `#` instead of with `$`) to let the user know he's in a root terminal. In fact, I think this should be the defaultt behaviour so you should have this different prompt already.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `su` you can add the `-, -l or --login` option to the command to "Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly." All according to the su man-page. These options will load the new users .bashrc or whatever file(s) apply to the shell being loaded.

For example `su -` will switch to the user root with all the same settings as if logged in directly as root from a terminal.

For more information see `man su`.

Answer (score 1):

I am lazy, I use the same .bashrc for root and my user. The main reason is I like to set a number of aliases (cp -I , etc).

Add this to set your prompt:

```
if [[ $EUID == 0 ]] ; then
    PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]\u\[\033[01;30m\]@\[\033[01;34m\]\h\[\033[01;30m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$' #RED
else
    PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[01;30m\]@\[\033[01;34m\]\h\[\033[01;30m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$' #Green

   # Comment out the above and uncomment the below for a blue user name.
   # PS1='\[\033[01;34m\]\u\[\033[01;30m\]@\[\033[01;34m\]\h\[\033[01;30m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$' #Blue
fi
```

The `if [[ $EUID == 0 ]]` sets your user name to red if running as root.

See : http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html for additional tips / options.

Answer (score 1):

add following lines to `.bashrc`

```
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ];
then # you are root, set red colour prompt
  PS1="\\w# "
else # normal
  PS1="\\w$ "
fi
```

you can also customize PS1 look at [this](http://www.linuxhelp.net/guides/bashprompt/bashprompt-print.php)